# XML shows blank page when linking XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="biblio.xsl"?>

<bibliography>
    <entry type="article">
        <title>A History of MOOCs, Open Online Courses</title>
        <author>Jane Karr</author>
        <year>2014</year>
    </entry> 
    <entry type="article">
        <title>Apple Co-Founder Creates Electronic ID Tags</title>
        <author>John Markoff</author>
        <year>2003</year>
    </entry> 
</bibliography>
```

XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Bibliography Entries</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:for-each select="bibliography/entry">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I don't link the XSLT file to the XML file, my XML file will output the tree structure in my browser's page but if I do link the XSLT file, it will show a blank page.

I am using Chrome, if it helps to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are loading the XML document from the file system and in that case Chrome for security reasons does not apply the linked XSLT, unless you start it with lowered security settings. Use F12 to open the browser console and check whether Chrome shows a message explaining why the Xslt was not applied.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't show anything obvious. All i have written in the console is `xml-stylesheet` and the xslt isn't present in the sources.

Comment: Yes, Chrome supports XSLT over HTTP but as I explained not from the local file system. Use Firefox if you need that.

Comment: Did you post the complete code? A closing `</xsl:stylesheet>` seems to be missing in that case.

Comment: Yes , sorry I forgot to indent it. +1 for explanation and Firefox suggestion. I'm using Firefox now which is working.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has still problem with launching their XML and XSLT files - right now Mozzila also for security reasons not apply the linked XSLT - you need to change the `privacy.file_unique_origin` property in `about:config` to false if you want apply your XSLT styling.

For those who not know - to go into `about:config` you just need to enter it in the Mozzila search bar.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works quite well. Just start Chrome as follows:

```
Chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried that and doesn't work. I'm thinking it's the browser's fault? I edited my question so it fits with the answer you provided. Unfortunately as I said, it does not work :(

Comment: Ok, got it - start your Chrome this way: `Chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`. By default local XSLT processing is disabled for security reasons.