# Why am I getting a blank output?

Tags: xml, xslt

On running the xml file via Chrome, I get a blank output while in Mozilla, the output is just plain text although it's supposed to be a table
This is the xml file:
List.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="list.xsl"?>
<papers>
    <info>
        <title>Neural Machine Translation and Artificial Intelligence : What Is Left for the Human Translator</title>
        <author>Laura Tomasello</author>
        <ISBN>6215912354785</ISBN>
        <domain>AI</domain>
    </info>
    <info>
        <title>Designing Preferences, Beliefs, and Identities for Artificial Intelligence</title>
        <author>Vincent Conitzer</author>
        <ISBN>3526293157315</ISBN>
        <domain>AI</domain>
    </info>
</papers>
```

This is the xsl file:
List.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html xlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body bgcolor="lightblue">
  <h1 style="color:blue"><i>Research Papers</i></h1>
    <table border="2" width="80%" height="50%">
      <tr bgcolor="grey">
        <th style="text-align:center;color:white">Title</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;color:white">Author</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;color:white">ISBN</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;color:white">Domain</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="papers/info">
      <tr bgcolor="white">
        <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="ISBN"/></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="domain"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Chrome gives me a blank output although the code looks fine. As per my intended code, the entered data should get displayed in a table with the styling I provided in the stylesheet but it's just plain text in Mozilla and a blank output in Chrome.

Comment: From where do you load the file, over HTTP(S) or from the file system? What does the console (F12) in Chrome show?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'm loading it from the file system and console shows this:  


Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:/Users/prath/Downloads/list.xsl from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/prath/Downloads/list.xml. 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.  



list.xml:1 Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///C:/Users/prath/Downloads/list.dtd from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/prath/Downloads/list.xml. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: If you want to use XSLT in Chrome with files loaded from the file system then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26662341/252228. As for Firefox, it used to support linking to XSLT for XML loaded over the file system but a change to fix a security hole unfortunately also disabled that feature for Firefox. There is some setting/preference in Firefox that might temporarily help but in general even for local files it looks like browser vendors expect to load over a local HTTP server and not directly from the file system.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Chrome still gives me the blank output but I'm getting the desired result in Microsoft Edge. Thanks a ton !